# Detect Youtube Play button action in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

How to detect action of Play button clicked in youtube in `wkwebview`, I have gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31469521/6165231), it is some how similar to my question but not duplicate and unanswered.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one callback when play button is clicked the very first time (doesn't notify about pause/play).

Use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049343/call-javascript-function-from-native-code-in-wkwebview/40730365#40730365) and replace `http://apple.com` with some youtube url.

Set a breakpoint in

`func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)`

Run in simulator and tap on youtube play button. You will get a callback in

`func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)`

method.

Comment: Hi, @Renatus, It is not working, have you checked it and is it working with in your end? let me know. particularly I'm using this url and want to get the action of play button `https://www.youtube.com/embed/owiwCIhc0I0` Thanks for your time though.